# Pylint does not acknowledge a module

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, visual-studio-code, pylint

I'm new to Django and haven't used much of the Python tooling.

The following line of code is being flagged by Pylint, despite working without issue.

```py
# main/management/commands/send_policy_notifications.py
from main import models
```

`No name 'models' in module 'main'pylint(no-name-in-module)`

The file structure follows:

```
.
├── Pipfile
├── Pipfile.lock
├── .env
├── .pylintrc
├── main
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── access_conditions.py
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── authentication.py
│   ├── flags.py
│   ├── management
│   │   └── commands
│   │       └── send_policy_notifications.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
└── manage.py
```

How can I configure Pylint to acknowledge that main contains models?

I'm using Visual Studio Code.

Comment: If you are using a virtual environment, you will need to install `pylint` inside your virtual environment. Running the command again after doing so should not produce the `no-name-in-module` warning.

Comment: You can disable this message only for this line by  appending this comment on the line `#pylint: disable=no-name-in-module`.

Comment: I'm aware of the `pylint: disable=` work around, but I'd prefer to fix the configuration issue.

The project is using a Pipenv, Pylint is installed and I've configured VSC to use the Python interpreter within the environment

Comment: is this a joke there is no models file in your main folder

Comment: @mick.io -For "_from main import models_", what do you want to import from the folder "mian"? If this is a hypothesis, provide a concrete example.